# Ignoring bash variables

Tags: bash

I'm working on creating a basic port scanner and have the scanner functioning, but I am struggling with adding a function that adjusts the timeout feature. How can I get bash to notice that $1 and $2 are not there and to proceed with reading $3 $4 $5 in the command line input? This is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash

changetime=$1
newtime=$2
host=$3
startport=$4
stopport=$5

if [ $1 = "-t" ]
then
    timeout "$newtime"
    echo "Timeout changed to $newtime second(s)."
else
    $changetime=0
    $newtime=0
fi
```

I'm able to get the scanner to work if I enter the bash command

```
./portscanner.sh -t 3 www.google.com 79 81
```

but bash does not like anything that I put after the else

Comment: This might help: `help shift`

Comment: Or simply `"${@:3}"` to reference the positional parameters beginning with the 3rd parameter (`"www.google.com 79 81"` here)

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code, including the reason why the code after the `else` is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 = "-t" ]
then
    changetime=$1
    newtime=$2
    #timeout "$newtime"
    echo "Timeout changed to $newtime second(s)."
    shift 2
else
    changetime=0
    newtime=0
fi

host=$1
startport=$2
stopport=$3

echo "newtime=$newtime host=$host startport=$startport stopport=$stopport"
```

For example:

```
$ ./portscanner -t 3 www.google.com 79 81
Timeout changed to 3 second(s).
newtime=3 host=www.google.com startport=79 stopport=81
$ ./portscanner www.google.com 79 81
newtime=0 host=www.google.com startport=79 stopport=81
```

The key change here is the addition of `shift`.  We can see how shift operates on the parameters with this command line example:

```
$ set -- 1 2 3 4
$ echo "$@"
1 2 3 4
$ shift 2
$ echo "$@"
3 4
```

Thus, `shift 2` removes the first two parameters, leaving the remaining ones (which are now renumbered to start again with `$1`).

Comment: That worked exactly how I needed it to. Thank you for the suggestion and the explanation of the `shift` command.